# AWS OpenSearch sniffing not works with spring-data-opensearch-starter dependency

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-opensearch

We use AWS Opensearch 2.9 in cloud as well as in development.
Sniffing works perfectly in development if we configure the environment as this: 
http.publish_host=localhost

Unfortunately the sniffing does not work in AWS environment. The connection to OpenSearch is successful, the application works fine, but produces this error like every 5 minute: 
org.opensearch.client.sniff.Sniffer : error while sniffing nodes

How can we configure AWS OpenSearch for sniffing? Or as I read here, we should not be sniffing. https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-sniffing-best-practices-what-when-why-how

We use this dependency in our spring-boot application:
https://github.com/opensearch-project/spring-data-opensearch 
I can't see any documentation here about sniffing. Maybe we need to disable sniffing in client side? If we need to how can we do that?

Comment: In your linked article under "when not to sniff" it lists "You’re working with cloud providers.".